# Using a spinner and button together to change screens

Tags: python, button, kivy, spinner, screen

I found [this](https://gist.github.com/hansent/3305675) code that showed me how to use a spinner to change screens. It works well in allowing me to switch screens, but I found that I also need to switch screens by using buttons on an individual screen.

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner

KV = """
<MainScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Button:
            text: 'Edit'
            on_press: root.goEdit()
        Label:
            text: 'Main Screen'

<HelpScreen>:
    Label:
        text: 'Help Screen'

<SettingsScreen>:
    Label:
        text: 'Settings Screen'

<EditScreen>:
    name: 'edit_Screen'
    text: 'Edit Screen'

<ScreenMenu>:
    text: 'main'
    values: ('main', 'help', 'settings')
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 200, 44
"""


class MainScreen(FloatLayout):

    def goEdit(self):
        MyApp.build.screen_layout.remove_widget(MyApp.screen)
        screen = EditScreen()
        MyApp.screen = screen
        MyApp.screen_layout.add_widget(MyApp.screen)


class HelpScreen(FloatLayout):
    pass

class SettingsScreen(FloatLayout):
    pass

class EditScreen(FloatLayout):
    pass

class ScreenMenu(Spinner):
    pass


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(KV)
        self.screen = None
        self.root = FloatLayout()
        self.screen_layout = FloatLayout()
        self.menu = ScreenMenu()
        self.root.add_widget(self.screen_layout)
        self.root.add_widget(self.menu)

        self.menu.bind(text=self.select_screen)
        self.show('main')
        return self.root

    def select_screen(self, *args):
        self.show(self.menu.text)

    def show(self, name='main'):
        if self.screen is not None:
            self.screen_layout.remove_widget(self.screen)
            self.screen = None
        if name == 'main':
            screen = MainScreen()
        elif name == 'help':
            screen = HelpScreen()
        elif name == 'settings':
            screen = SettingsScreen()
        else:
            raise Exception('Invalid screen name')
        self.screen = screen
        self.screen_layout.add_widget(screen)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

As you can see, this is almost the exact code as found in the link above, the only difference is that here, I create an "Edit" button that when clicked, refers to the goEdit() method of the "MainScreen" class.

```
on_press: root.goEdit()
```

My problem is I don't know how to create the goEdit() method so that, when called, it goes to the "EditScreen" while also having the spinner work ( it goes to the "MainScreen", "HelpScreen" and "SettingScreen" screens). The code I tried in goEdit() clearly doesn't work.

I have also tried changing the inherited classes from FloatLayout to Screen:

```
class MainScreen(Screen):   
    def goEdit(self):
        self.parent.current = 'edit_Screen'         
class HelpScreen(Screen):
    pass
class SettingsScreen(Screen):
    pass
class EditScreen(Screen):
    pass
class ScreenMenu(Spinner):
    pass
```

Here I tried to switch screens using this code:

```
self.parent.current = 'edit_Screen'
```

but when clicking the 'edit' button, nothing happens, I don't even get error messages.

Essentially what I want is for the spinner to work as it does in the example link, but I also need the 'edit' button to also change screens. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Instead, I would think about working with a ScreenManager and defining your individual screens as children of the ScreenManager in your .kv file. Then from the button widgets on each of your screens, you can bind an on_press or on_release event as: root.manager.current = 'menu'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

Please refer to the explanations, example and output for details.

### kv String

1. Replace *root.edit()* with *app.show(name='edit')*
2. Replace *name: 'edit_screen'* with *Label:*
3. Indent *text: 'Edit Screen'*

### Python Script

1. Replace all the codings in *MainScreen* with *pass*
2. Add *elif name == 'edit': screen = EditScreen()* statement in method *show*

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner

KV = """
<MainScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Button:
            text: 'Edit'
            on_press: app.show(name='edit')
        Label:
            text: 'Main Screen'

<HelpScreen>:
    Label:
        text: 'Help Screen'

<SettingsScreen>:
    Label:
        text: 'Settings Screen'

<EditScreen>:
    Label:
        text: 'Edit Screen'

<ScreenMenu>:
    text: 'main'
    values: ('main', 'help', 'settings')
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 200, 44
"""


class MainScreen(FloatLayout):
    pass


class HelpScreen(FloatLayout):
    pass


class SettingsScreen(FloatLayout):
    pass


class EditScreen(FloatLayout):
    pass


class ScreenMenu(Spinner):
    pass


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(KV)
        self.screen = None
        self.root = FloatLayout()
        self.screen_layout = FloatLayout()
        self.menu = ScreenMenu()
        self.root.add_widget(self.screen_layout)
        self.root.add_widget(self.menu)

        self.menu.bind(text=self.select_screen)
        self.show('main')
        return self.root

    def select_screen(self, *args):
        self.show(self.menu.text)

    def show(self, name='main'):
        if self.screen is not None:
            self.screen_layout.remove_widget(self.screen)
            self.screen = None
        if name == 'main':
            screen = MainScreen()
        elif name == 'help':
            screen = HelpScreen()
        elif name == 'settings':
            screen = SettingsScreen()
        elif name == 'edit':
            screen = EditScreen()
        else:
            raise Exception('Invalid screen name')
        self.screen = screen
        self.screen_layout.add_widget(screen)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - MainScreen @ AppStartup]
[image: Img02 - Spinner @ MainScreen]
[image: Img03 - EditScreen]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple example using the ScreenManager:

**Python**

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition

class Screen1(Screen):

    pass

class Screen2(Screen):

    pass

class Screen3(Screen):

    pass

class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):

    def changescreen(self, value):

        try:
            if value!='Choose a Value...':
                self.current = value
        except:
            print('No screen named ' + value)

#Main application
class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.sm = MyScreenManager()
        return self.sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

**kv**

```
<MyScreenManager>:

    Screen1:
        name: 'screen1'
    Screen2:
        name: 'screen2'
    Screen3:
        name: 'screen3'

<Screen1>:

    GridLayout:

        rows: 2
        padding: 20
        spacing: 20

        Button:
            text: 'Go to Screen 2'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'screen2'

        Button:
            text: 'Go to Screen 3'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'screen3'

        Spinner:
            text: 'Choose a Value...'
            values: ['screen2', 'screen3']
            on_text:
                root.manager.changescreen(self.text)
                self.text = 'Choose a Value...'

        Label:
            text: 'You are on ' + root.name

<Screen2>:

    GridLayout:

        rows: 2
        padding: 20
        spacing: 20

        Button:
            text: 'Go to Screen 1'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'screen1'

        Button:
            text: 'Go to Screen 3'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'screen3'

        Spinner:
            text: 'Choose a Value...'
            values: ['screen1', 'screen3']
            on_text:
                root.manager.changescreen(self.text)
                self.text = 'Choose a Value...'

        Label:
            text: 'You are on ' + root.name

<Screen3>:

    GridLayout:

        rows: 2
        padding: 20
        spacing: 20

        Button:
            text: 'Go to Screen 1'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'screen1'

        Button:
            text: 'Go to Screen 2'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'screen2'

        Spinner:
            text: 'Choose a Value...'
            values: ['screen1', 'screen2']
            on_text:
                root.manager.changescreen(self.text)
                self.text = 'Choose a Value...'

        Label:
            text: 'You are on ' + root.name
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I really do need to use the spinner screen switching method found in the link (or another alternative) for navigation purposes, as well as having separate buttons also switch to different screens.

Comment: Edited my answer to include a spinner that incorporates screen changes. There is likely a more efficient means of accomplishing this, however I think this is the simplest example to understand. Hope this helps!